# Display each product with different options on separate line in PHP

Tags: php, session

So, I have a shopping cart that allows you to select a JAR file and then select the contents of the JAR file (i.e. options).

When the product is "added to the cart" the following script is ran:

```
$productID = $_POST['id'];

$action = $_POST['action'];

if(!$_POST['id'] | !$_POST['action'])
{
    $productID = $_GET['id'];

    $action = $_GET['action'];
}

// Creates the array of the options chosen for the item.
$optionsSelected = array();
if (!empty($_POST['productOption']))
{
   foreach ($_POST['productOption'] as $options)
      $optionsSelected[] = $options;

switch($action) {
   case "add":
      $_SESSION['cart'][$productID]++;
      $_SESSION['options'.$productID]= $optionsSelected;
      header('location: /shop/cart');

   break;

   case "remove":

      $_SESSION['cart'][$productID]--;
      unset($_SESSION['options'.$productID]);
      if($_SESSION['cart'][$productID] == 0)
      {
          unset($_SESSION['cart'][$productID]);
          unset($_SESSION['options'.$productID]);
      }
      header('location: /shop/cart');
   break;
}
```

And then it is displayed out like so in the shopping cart:

```
<?php if (count($_SESSION['options'.$id]) > 0): ?>
   <?php foreach($_SESSION['options'.$id] as $key => $options): ?>
       <p><?php echo $options; ?></p>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

(This is only the portion for the options. To see the full shopping cart page code [click here](https://github.com/TheGreenPanda/ShoppingCart123) (recommended))

Right now, the session for the options get overwritten if you go and add another product with the same ID to the cart with different options. And that first set of options is gone!

I want to make the shopping cart realize that there is already a session of options set for the ID and that it needs to make something different to display an entirely new line in the shopping cart to display it and preserve both option sets for the product id. To see the website, visit [candykingdom.org/shop/products.php](http://www.candykingdom.org/shop/products.php).

I have no idea where to go from here. I have been searching and staring at my screen for days, but I haven't gotten anywhere. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Sidenote: I see no mention of `session_start();` for any of your files, in your question anyway.

Comment: @Fred-ii- All the files shared here are included in other files that do in fact include the `session_start();`

Comment: Typo? You have a missing `|` in `if(!$_POST['id'] | !$_POST['action'])` which should read as `if(!$_POST['id'] || !$_POST['action'])` which also shows up in your [`github file`](https://github.com/TheGreenPanda/ShoppingCart123/blob/master/cart_actions.php)

Comment: Okay..... Maybe to a solution to my problem? I'm quite irritated that I can't figure this one out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store them separately, regardless of a common product ID. Maybe something like this

```
$key = $productID . ":" . base64_encode(serialize($optionsSelected));
$_SESSION['cart'][$key]++;
```

This can easily be reversed on the other end:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $quantity) {
  $product = explode(':', $key);
  $productId = $product[0];
  $optionsSelected = unserialize(base64_decode($product[1]));
}
```

Comment: Will you show the `This can easily be reversed on the other end.` portion.

Comment: Now, I don't believe `$key` is defined in the second file for viewing?

Comment: Woops missed the quantity, sorry. That should work now. (really should test stuff before I post haha) ... obviously missing some things like checking if there's an entry first before adding one to it, but you should get the general idea.

Comment: Okay, So that got what I wanted!!!! Thank you! Except now my remove button doesn't work :(

Comment: Will you help me remove these items from the shopping cart. It does not good if the whole system doesn't work. Check out my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21962805/shopping-cart-remove-no-longer-working

Answer (score 0):

```
case "add": 
    $_SESSION['cart'][$productID]++;
    $_SESSION['options'.$productID]= $optionsSelected;
    header('location: /shop/cart');
    break;
```

With the line:
    $_SESSION['options'.$productID]= $optionsSelected;

you are always overwriting the same variable with the new options of the newly added product. You should turn that variable into an array to be able to hold multiple set of options.
    $_SESSION['options'.$productID]**[]**= $optionsSelected;
So now the display portion should change in this way:
    if (count($_SESSION['options'.$id]) > 0):
       $options_combinations = count($_SESSION['options'.$id]);
              $i = 0;

```
    foreach($_SESSION['options'.$id] as $options):
        $i++;
        foreach($options as $option):
            php echo $option;
        endforeach;
        if ($options_combinations > $i:
            echo '-----------'
        endif;
    endforeach;
endif;
```