# Increment variable for each set of options in shopping cart

Tags: php

So I have a set of options set for each item added to a shopping cart with this code:

```
$optionsSelected = array();
if (!empty($_POST['productOption']))
{
   foreach ($_POST['productOption'] as $options)
      $optionsSelected[] = $options;
}
$_SESSION['options'.$productID] = $optionsSelected;

$key = $productID . ":" . base64_encode(serialize($optionsSelected));

$_SESSION['cart'][$key]++;

header('location: /shop/cart');
```

For more details on exactly how this works, See my [previous question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21948691/display-each-product-with-different-options-on-separate-line-in-php). Don't want to place too much here to create a duplicate question!

Now that I have got that all working, I ran into another problem. And my solution was to create a variable that increases after each set of options for a certain product ID.

See, my database table has an `identifier` column in it. All these options are input into the database table. And the identifier needs to match the options set for the product ID.

For example, let's say I have the following shopping cart layout:

```
Product Name            Option Names        Qty 

33.8 Oz Jar             Runts, Bears        1

33.8 Oz Jar             Swirls, Twists      1
```

Now this will be inserted into my database table as so:

```
orderNumber    optionName    productID        identifier

randomNumb     Runts         33.8 Oz Jar      

randomNumb     Bears         33.8 Oz Jar 

randomNumb     Swirls        33.8 Oz Jar 

randomNumb     Twists        33.8 Oz Jar
```

You'll notice the identifier field is empty, That is what I am trying to add... I need the following to happen, to match the jars the contents should be within:

```
orderNumber    optionName    productID        identifier

randomNumb     Runts         33.8 Oz Jar      1   

randomNumb     Bears         33.8 Oz Jar      1 

randomNumb     Swirls        33.8 Oz Jar      2

randomNumb     Twists        33.8 Oz Jar      2
```

I thought up the following code: (note the $identifier variable)

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $quantity)
    {
        $product = explode(':', $key);
        $productId = $product[0];
        $optionsSelected = unserialize(base64_decode($product[1]));
        $id = $productId;

        $statement = "INSERT INTO KC_OrderProducts (orderNumber, productID, qty) VALUES (:orderNumber, :productID, :qty);";

        $query = $db->prepare($statement); 

        $results = $query->execute(array(
            ":orderNumber"      => $orderNumber,
            ":productID"        => $id,
            ":qty"              => $quantity
        )); 

        $identifier = 0;

        if($optionsSelected > 0){
            foreach($optionsSelected as $option)
            {
                $identifier++;

                $statement = "INSERT INTO KC_OrderOptions (orderNumber, optionName, productID, identifier) VALUES (:orderNumber, :optionName, :productID, :identifier)";

                $query = $db->prepare($statement);

                $results = $query->execute(array(
                    ":orderNumber"      => $orderNumber,
                    ":optionName"       => $option,
                    ":productID"        => $id,
                    ":identifier"       => $identifier
                ));
            }
        }
    }
```

This code got me close, My table resulted in looking like the following:

```
orderNumber    optionName    productID        identifier

randomNumb     Runts         33.8 Oz Jar      2   

randomNumb     Bears         33.8 Oz Jar      1 

randomNumb     Swirls        33.8 Oz Jar      2

randomNumb     Twists        33.8 Oz Jar      1
```

As you can see, the options no longer match the products, This means every order will be fulfilled wrong, simply because the order was jumbled up.

I tried placing the `$identifier = 0;` outside of the `foreach` block but that resulted in each row in the table getting a new identifier number. `1,2,3,4` rather than `1,1,2,2`

So, my question is, what do I need to do with the `$identifier = 0;` and `$identifier++` to achieve what I am trying to. Or is there a better way to handle this?

**UPDATE**

The $optionsSelected varialble, when `var_dump()` returns the following array when ran.

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "Runts" [1]=> string(5) "Bears" } array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "Swirls" [1]=> string(6) "Twists" }
```

Comment: **Still** no solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the initialization of `$identifier` so it's executed immediately before the outer `foreach` loop:

```
$identifier = 0; // <-- to here

foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $quantity)
    {
    ...
```

and move the incrementation of `$identifier` so it's executed immediately before the inner loop:

```
        if($optionsSelected > 0){

            $identifier++; // <-- to here

            foreach($optionsSelected as $option)
            {
            ...
```

This way `$identifier` is initialized for processing the entire cart (rather than for each cart *item*), and it's incremented for each time your script adds *a set of options* (rather than for *each option of a set*).