# Shopping cart "remove" no longer working

Tags: php

I managed to get all my products to add with options for each item and each of those appearing on a separate line and to submit properly.

([see my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21950921/increment-variable-for-each-set-of-options-in-shopping-cart))

Now when I try to remove the item that has options set to it, it does not remove anything. My code for adding is like so:

```
switch($action) {
    case "add": 

       $_SESSION['options'.$productID] = $optionsSelected;

       $key = $productID . ":" . base64_encode(serialize($optionsSelected));

       $_SESSION['cart'][$key]++;

       header('location: /shop/cart');

    break;
```

And then my remove case is like so:

```
        case "remove": 

            $key = $_GET['key'];
            $product = explode(':', $key);
            $productId = $product[0];
            $optionsSelected = unserialize(base64_decode($product[1]));

            $_SESSION['cart'][$key]--;

            if($_SESSION['cart'][$key] == 0)
            {
                unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);
            }

            header('location: /shop/cart');

        break;
```

The remove function is triggered with a URL like the following with each option:

```
<a href="/shop/actions/cart_actions.php?action=remove&id=<?php echo $item['id']; ?>&key=<?php echo $key; ?>" class="btn btn-danger">
```

Now if I remove a product that has no options set to it, it removes just fine. If the product has options it does not remove.

**update**

When I `<?php var_dump($_SESSION['cart']); ?>` I get the following:

```
array(2) { ["433771:YToyOntpOjA7czo1OiJSdW50cyI7aToxO3M6NzoiU2l4bGV0cyI7fQ=="]=> int(1) ["433771:YToyOntpOjA7czoyMToiU3dlZGlzaCBGaXNoIEFzc29ydGVkIjtpOjE7czozMToiQmVhcnkgQmx1ZSBSYXNiZXJyeSBHdW1taSBCZWFycyI7fQ=="]=> int(1) }
```

Comment: **Still** No Solution!

Comment: Apparently no one in the world knows either.... great.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I haven't checked the site for a couple of days. I tested the code above and the relevant parts work as intended, but I do see some issues. Have you tried to `var_dump($_SESSION)` to see if things are being set correctly in the first place?

Try this, it assumes `$productID` and `$optionsSelected` are defined somewhere above as needed, and that the session has been started. Tested working.

```
<?php

switch ($action) {
    case "add":

        $key = $productID . ":" . base64_encode(serialize($optionsSelected));

        // ensure the cart array exists
        if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
            $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
        }

        // create entry, or add to it
        if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'][$key])) {
            $_SESSION['cart'][$key] = 1;
        } else {
            $_SESSION['cart'][$key]++;
        }

        header('location: /shop/cart');
        // always exit after sending a location header, or the rest of the script will continue to execute first
        exit;
        break;

    case "remove":

        $key = $_GET['key'];

        if (isset($_SESSION['cart'], $_SESSION['cart'][$key])) {
            if ($_SESSION['cart'][$key] > 1) {
                $_SESSION['cart'][$key]--;
            } else {
                unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);
            }
        }

        header('location: /shop/cart');
        exit;
        break;
}
```

Comment: Will try in a couple minutes.

Comment: This still did not remove it. Check my updated answer for a var_dump();

Comment: Can you also `var_dump($_GET)`?